# Change value of a variable depending on another in python

Tags: python

So let's say I have two variables, `var` and `text`. I would like to know how I could change the value of `text` depending on what `var` is equal to.

For example, i receive `var` and it's value is "this". I would then like `text` to get the value 1. If `var` is then equal to "that", `text` would then be equal to 2.

I would like not to use `if ... elif` as there could be quite a lot of values.

Sorry for my english, I could try to re-explain if it's not clear

Comment: What is the problem with `if..else` ?

Comment: Could your please [edit] your question and include that illustrates your problem? Please also include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dict :

```
yourdict = {'this':1, 'that':2, ...}
text = yourdict[var]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary to keep the mappings:

```
check = { 'this': 1, 'that' : 2 }
```

Then you can use the value dynamically:

```
text = check.get(var)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has no switch/case statement. Best way to go is using a dictionary, which I find more clear even in languages providing a switch statement.

E.g.

```
cases = {
    'this': 'blah',
    'that': 'blub'
}

var = 'this'
text = cases.get(var, 'your default value here')
print(text)
```